# How to remove a data in MySQL database after certain period automatically?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `user_logs`. I want to remove the logs every 30 days. Is there any possible way to do it automatically. I am using `php and mysql` in my project.

Comment: Set up a job to run every day, clear out entries that are older than 30 days.

Comment: sounds like a job for a cronjob!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup an Event to delete record older than 30 days, like :

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `Clean_Older_Than_1_month_logs`
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY_HOUR
COMMENT 'Clean up user_logs older than 1 month.'
DO
    DELETE FROM user_logs
    WHERE user_logs_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, You should use 'setInterval()' in Js for ajax call after 30-days.

**index.html** page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
        alert("Event Fire");
        $.ajax({
            url: "30_day_event.php",
            success: function(result){
                alert('database operation done');
            }
        });
    }, 1000*60*60*24*30);
});
```

**30_day_event.php** page

```
//your your logic to delete data from user_logs table
//your callback code
```

Comment: People would have to keep the webpage open for 30 days though. Not very user friendly

Comment: 'setInterval(function(){ 
        alert("Event Fire");
        $.ajax({
            url: "30_day_event.php",
            success: function(result){
                alert('database operation done');
            }
        });
    }, 1000*60*60*24*30);' 

if you convert this code snippet in node.js it will work with just severer running.